# Vue listen to deep props not triggering

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have to following set of components to create a table

- table - uses header (passing columns) and a list of rows giving rowData & columns
- header - utilises the passed columns and uses headerCell passing the column property
- headerCell
- row - loops over the given columns and shows the data

My problem is as follows, I want that a click (say visibility) on the header updates the columnDefinition with visible true | false and is watched by the rows to update visiblity accordingly.
However whatever i tried the watcher still not triggering. What am I doing wrong?

```js
/**** Table ***/
<template>
    <table>
    <HeaderRow :columns=computedColumns :groups=columnGroups v- 
        on:column:change=onColumnChange></HeaderRow>
    <tbody>
         <Row v-for="(row, index) in computedData" :key=index :data=row 
              :columns=computedColumns :rowIndex=index ></Row>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
<script>
import Row from "./Row.vue";
import HeaderRow from "./HeaderRow.vue";
export default {
 computed: {
    /* If this.columns is set (columns is a prop) than map it to a new array, otherwise 
       try to identify the columns from the row data */
  computedColumns: function() {
      if (this.columns && this.columns.length) {
    return this.columns.map(col => {
                    return Object.assign({
                        title: '',
                        name: '',
                        description: undefined,
                        className: '',
                        style: '',
                        visible: true,
                        sort: false,
                        group: undefined,
                        defaultValue: undefined,
                    }, col)
                });
   } else {
    return (
     this.data &&
     this.data
      .map(function(row) {
       return Object.keys(row);
      })
      .reduce(function(arr, row) {
       return arr.concat(
        row.filter(function(value, index) {
         return arr.indexOf(value) == -1;
        })
       );
      }, [])
      .map(function(column) {
       return {
        title: column,
        name: column
       };
      })
    );
   }
  },
   }

/*** HeaderCell ***/ 
    <th @click=toggleColumn :class=className><span>{{column.title}}</span></th>
    ...
    ...
    toggleColumn: function(e) {
      this.visible = !this.visible;
      this.column.visible = this.visible;
      this.$emit("column:change", {
       column: this.column,
       columnIndex: this.columnIndex
      });
     }

/***   Row  ****/
    <template>
    <tr>
      <td  v-for="(cell, index) in cells" :key=index :class=cell.className 
    :style=cell.style v-html=cell.value ></td>
    </tr>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
    props: {
        data: {
            default: []
        },
        columns: {
            default: "",
            type: Array
        },
        rowIndex: {
            default: -1
        }
    },
    watch: {
        columns: {
            handler: function () {
                console.log('change occurred')
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
```

Comment: what is the data format of your props=`columns`?

Comment: Can you please show us what ```computedColumns``` method is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that your columns prop is using `computedColumns`.

It would be good to see what this is because it is likely that it is losing reactivity when you return the value from that computed property.

for example, if you have the following in your parent:

```
computed: {
    computedColumns() {
        // return new set of columns
        return [
            {id: 1, visible: false},
            {id: 2, visible: false},
            {id: 3, visible: false}
        ]
    }
}
```

Then the `computedColumns` property will not have any reactivity. Therefore you will not be able to watch it.

However, if you have as an example:

```
data() {
    return {
        columns: [
            {id: 1, visible: false},
            {id: 2, visible: false},
            {id: 3, visible: false}
        ]
    }
},
computed: {
    computedColumns() {
        // return reactive data attribute
        return this.columns
    }
}
```

Because you are referencing the original data attribute, you will keep reactivity.

So you might have to rethink how you set the columns property to maintain reactivity.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81v5nw6x/) that outlines this example.

Comment: I've updated the original code snippet to show the computed. Basically I have the second scenario however its utilising a map function which is probably stopping reactivity.

Comment: As suggested above, reactivity is lost with the computed columns. Instead what i did was added a watch on the columns prop and assigned computedColumns (now under data) with the appropriate transformation, rendering it reactive

Comment: Great, glad you got it working. Feel free to vote up the answer if you think it is worth it. Cheers